# How do I get the arrow keys to change the focus to the next element in a threepenny-gui grid?

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

The tab key changes the focus in a grid to the next element. How do I get the up/down/left/right arrow keys to work also?

Answer (score 2):

it simple you first identify the arrow key value and write code onKeyPress and check value of key and write appropriate code and let me know what happen.